# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: react-router

I am writing react route and in this code it shows an unexpected error of "<" at line no.8 . My code is

```
var React = require('react');
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;

var App=React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="header">
         <h1>Welcome to Twitter</h1>
         <nav className="links">
            <link to ="https://about.twitter.com/"> About </link>
            <link to="/login"> Login </link>
            <link to="/sign_up"> Sign Up </link>
         </nav>
         {this.props.children}
       </div>
    )
  }
})
React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
       <Route path="login" components={Login} />
       <Route path="sign_up" components={Sign_Up} />
  </Router>
),document.body)
```

Please help me out,cause I have already wasted lots of time for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending this code directly to the browser? Because it is **jsx** and needs to be transformed. Take a look at [reactify](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify).